# Expandable/collapsible JPanel that smoothly resizes JFrame to the left

Tags: java, swing, jframe, resize, collapsable

I'm trying to create a Java window (with a `JFrame`) that is able to resize itself when the user clicks a button in order to display some extra components (`JLabel` and `JButton` components) in a `JPanel`. These extra stuff panel is hidden when the window shows up. The window is located on the right border of the screen (Windows desktop), so it must grow **to the left** when the hidden panel becomes visible.

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                               +-------------------------------+ |
|                                               |                               | |
|            BEFORE:                            |             600px             | |
|                                               |                               | |
|                                               +-------------------------------+ |
|                                                                                 |
|                                                                                 |
|                                         <---                                    |
|                                       +-------+-------------------------------+ |
|                                       |       |                               | |
|            AFTER:                     | 150px |             600px             | |
|                                       |       |                               | |
|                                       +-------+-------------------------------+ |
|                                                                                 |
|                                                                                 |
|                                                                                 |
|                                                                                 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I've implemented a first version by using a vertical `JSplitPane`: the main window is on the right side and the extra panel is on the left side. When the user clicks the button, the system:

1. sets the visibility of the extra panel to true.
2. resizes the `JFrame` to width = 750px (its original width + the width of the extra panel).
3. moves the window 150 px to the left because resizing is done **to the right**.

This algorithm works, but I have a very unpleasant "flash" effect during resizing/moving.

Is there a way to make this resizing/moving step smooth? Or, preferably, is there some swing or third part component that implements this kind of thing (a hidden panel that shows up and resizes the window smoothly **to the left** and **without moving it**)?

Comment: The programmer should not be guessing how big a GUI needs to be. Use `pack()` on the top level container for the necessary size as calculated by the JRE for that GUI, in that PLAF, on that OS at this moment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried that, the width of my extra panel increases to the right and reduces the width of the main panel. Maybe I should try without a JSplitPane ? And even if it works, I think that the JFrame will always be resized to the right.